# How to create same paradigm of monobehaviour and processing in C++

Tags: c++, sdl2, processing, monobehaviour

Having worked with monobehaviour and processing before, is it possible to create the same paradigm both frameworks use which basically is writing all code in two main functions, start/setup and update/draw. To further elaborate, much like working in unity when creating a new script the user is presented with two functions a start and an update. The first function always gets called on the first frame while the latter gets called every frame there is no main function present only these two. I'd like to imitate that same structure on to c++.

Comment: This looks like a straightforward application of virtual functions. Have you encountered any specific problem in implementing this paradigm this way?

Comment: I'm aware it'll be the utilization of virtual functions, however I'm looking to completely hide the main function and not give it use for the user much like the frameworks I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you edit your question to describe in more detail what you mean by "hide the main function"?

Comment: Sure I'll edit it

Comment: So you want to create some kind of blackbox engine based on an entity-component architecture, and allow the users to write two entry points into each of your components? Why?

Comment: Not two entry points for each component, but a universal entry points for the whole program just like processing